# Post a form to a spring controller, issue with localdate

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring

I use thymeleaf 3 with spring boot 2

I try to save a form

My controller

```
@PostMapping("template/new/samplings")
@ResponseBody
public SamplingsDto save(@RequestBody SamplingsDto samplings) {
    return samplingsService.save(samplings);
}
```

I do a submit, I need to modify some value (date) to be sure to send it to standard format.

My js

```
var receptionDate =  $("#samplingsReceptionDatePicker").data('daterangepicker').startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var buildDate =  $("#samplingsBuildDatePicker").data('daterangepicker').startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

$("#samplingsForm").submit(function (e){
     var data = $("#samplingsForm").serializeArray();
     data.find(item => item.name === 'receptionDate').value = receptionDate;
     data.find(item => item.name === 'buildDate').value = buildDate;

     $.ajax({
         type:"post",
         url: "/template/new/samplings",
         data: data,
         contentType: "application/json",
         success: function(data){ 
         },
         error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         }
     });
});
```

In SamplingsDto,

receptionDate is a LocalDate dataType

Error I get

> 2018-05-19 14:03:49.824  WARN 12422 --- [nio-8080-exec-3]
>   .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused
>   by Handler execution:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'receptionDate': was expecting
>   ('true', 'false' or 'null'); nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token
>   'receptionDate': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')  at
>   [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 15]

Edit img of data
[image]

Comment: What are you actually sending? E.g., I've never modified data in-place using `value` when it's just a serialized form. Check what's on the wire.

Comment: i edited to post an image of the data